# How to create a 'style master' winforms control

Tags: c#, winforms, styles

I have an application with several DataGridView controls. I would like to create a master control or component (I'm not sure which one to use) where I can define basic coloring and behavior. However, since all DataGridView controls have different columns in the application I want to define columns after placing a new instance on the form and not in the master form.

Can you suggest a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have something like your own MasterGridView where you define all common behavior, colour, etc.. & then inherit all respective datagridviews from this one.

```
public class MasterDataGridView: System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
{
    public MasterDataGridView()
    {
        BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        // define other behaviours
    }
}

public class OrdersDataGridView : MasterDataGridView
{
   // data binding, column addition etc can be handle in respective grid views
}


public class ReportsDataGridView : MasterDataGridView
{
}
```

...
etc.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do it in the designer, instead of code? I mean like setting the backColor.

Comment: I did not get you. You can always have your `MasterDataGridView` component available in the designer. Just create a class library project and write the class what I have shown above. `Build it and you will see that MasterDataGridView coming up in the ToolBox on the Right Pane.` Just drag drop and set the Properties. Its the normal way you write custom components in Winforms.

Comment: What I meant is that I wanted to find a way to set the master backcolor to yellow in the designer (instead from code as in your example), so that once I pull the component from the Toolbox I will have yellow background. Anyway, your answer is acceptable, thanks for helping.